# Will splitting a LAN connection from a router with a switch slow down the ping go high whenever I transfer files from my PC to the NAS?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I got a new NAS (My Cloud EX2 Ultra) as a 'beginner solution' to get into networking.

Since my DLAN module (internet connection to router via power grid in the wall) with two ethernet ports to which I connected my NAS as well as my PC slows down the network/file transfer speed to 100Mbit/s I figured out after testing a bit that I have to connect these two devices directly to my router.

The problem is that the router is in the next room so I would need a long ethernet cable.

According to the answers to existing question in this forum I found out that in this situation a network switch (a Gigabit switch in my case for 1Gbit/s) is the way to go.

I still have a few concerns before buying a switch:

1. Will 'splitting up' the connection to the router using a switch cause the internet speed of my PC to slow down the ping go high whenever I transfer files from my PC to the NAS?
2. Is connecting two devices to a switch the same as connecting them separately to the router using two cables, thus behave the same way?

Comment: Network throughput is measured in "_bits per second_"... if you keep converting to "_bytes per second_" you're going to get confused or misunderstood.

Comment: Please also draw a diagram showing your network topology, and link to the relevant questions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will 'splitting up' the connection to the router using a switch cause the internet speed of my PC to slow down/the ping go high whenever I transfer files from my PC to the NAS?

Yes, but not because of the switch. Network connection to your computer has a top speed cap imposed by hardware, say 100 Mbps. If your Internet connection is also 100 Mbps, but at the same time you're transferring data from/to NAS at 50 Mbps, then you only have 50 Mpbs left for the Internet connection. Total throughput of your computer is capped, no matter if it's connected directly to the router or through a switch.

> Is connecting two devices to a switch the same as connecting them separately to the router using two cables, thus behave the same way?

It's not the same, but effectively the same, ie. you won't notice a difference.

Strictly speaking, when NAS and PC will communicate through LAN, router won't know about it. Switch will learn which devices are connected to what ports and will only forward network packets to ports where it makes sense. For example when it sees a packet from NAS to PC, it will only forward it to the port there PC is connected. Router will never receive that packet, so it will never even learn that NAS and PC attempted to communicate<sup>[1]</sup>.

You'll even be able to turn the router off and PC <---> NAS connection will still work. <sup>[2]</sup>

Transfer speed between PC and NAS will be the lowest of these:

- Speed supported by network adapters in PC and NAS
- Speed configured on PC and NAS
- Speed supported by the switch
- Speed allowed by network cables

For example, you can have 1 Gbit network adapters in PC and NAS and 1 Gbit switch, but with Cat5 cables speed will drop to 100 Mbps because Cat5 can't sustain reliable 1 Gbit bandwidth.

Other factors, such as speed supported by router or switch <---> router cable quality won't affect speed for PC <---> NAS transfers.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> That description is slightly simplified. Initially, switch doesn't know which device is connected to which port, so it will forward packets to all other ports and connected devices will just ignore packets that don't designate them as recipients. Over time the switch will associate devices with ports. For example when it receives an incoming packet *from* NAS on physical port 3, it will assume NAS is connected to port 3 and all future packets addressed *to* NAS will only be forwarded to port 3. So strictly speaking, router will receive some wandering packets until switch learns about physical ports where PC and NAS are connected. It won't affect network performance or stability, though.

<sup>[2]</sup> Assuming they have their IP addresses assigned. This is usually done by DHCP server running on the router, so with default configuration router is necessary to provide IP addresses to PC and NAS, then it can be turned off. IP address leases from DHCP expire over time, so eventually you'd have to turn router back on to renew IPs. This can be mitigated either by assigning static IPs or by running DHCP on PC or NAS instead of the router. (thanks to @Attie for a good point in the comments)

Comment: "_You'll even be able to turn the router off_" - unless DHCP is on the router, leases expire, and the hosts fall back to autoconfiguration... be careful with such suggestions.

Comment: @gronostaj When I transfer files from the PC to the NAS or vice versa, does the data go through the switch without going to the router and back? If so, what is the maximum transfer speed and what is the limiting factor? (the switch, my PC etc.)

Comment: @Kenta1561 I've updated the answer.

Comment: @gronostaj Thanks for the detailed answer! I tested it today by using an existing Gigabit switch in the living room and connecting the NAS & PC to the switch and that to the router (all with Cat5e cables) and could reach up to 120 MB/s (I think it's about 1Gbit/s?). Everything worked as I imagined it so I bought another Gigabit network switch for my room. Thanks for the help!

Comment: 1 MB/s = 8 Mbps, so 1 Gbps is exactly 125 MB/s. 120 is a good result, I'd expect larger protocol overhead. Glad I could help!